# Получить данные с модального окна

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть класс основного окна MainWindow. С него я запускаю (допустим, при авторизации) модальное окно авторизации с полями "Логин", "Пароль" (`lineLogin`, `linePass` соответственно).
Я знаю, что можно создать сигнал в классе модального окна

```
signals:
  void sendData(QString login, QString password);
```

и создать слот в классе главного окна и там мы производим действия с данными

```
private slots:
   void getData(QString login, QString password);
```

далее всё это дело соединить в классе главного окна

```
connect(&modal, SIGNAL(sendData(QString, QString)), SLOT(getData(QString, QString));
```

А само окно мы вызываем, допустим в слоте `on_actionC_triggered()`

```
modal.exec();
```

Но меня напрягает:

1. Создание лишнего слота с принятием данных с модального окна.
2. Какая-то громоздкость в обычном принятии значений полей.

Как можно получить данные прямо с `modal.exec()` , если это возможно, чтобы обработать значения полей `lineLogin` и `linePass` прямо в `on_actionC_triggered()`?

Если без вышеописанных методов не получится, то как можно уменьшить код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс диалога авторизации:

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

    QString getLogin() const;
    QString getPassword() const;

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};
```

Вызов диалога:

```
void MainWindow::on_toolButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog dialog(this);

    if(dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        QString login = dialog.getLogin();
        QString password = dialog.getPassword();
        //..что-то делаем дальше
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не поверите, но я вот прям сейчас, в эту же минуту так попробовал сделать. Да, заработало. Спасибо за внимание. Метод и правда действенный